# Remove Duplicates with or without sorting

Tags: excel

I have a large column of texts (5 digit integers concatenated with two letters, like: 12345AB ) and values (up to 8 digit positive integers, like: 12345678) . The list is around 12,200 total and when I do remove duplicates, it reduces to 7015 total. If I sort the result and then do another remove duplicates, I am left with 6324 entries. On the other hand if I sort first and then do remove duplicates, I am left with 6324 entries.

Is this a common issue that when number and text are mixed up that removing duplicates works only after sorting.

I can upload my file if this is not a common issue and is a problem with my file. I'm guessing if the row starts with numbers (text) then the excel search algorithm only goes down the column till such a point that it stops seeing numbers (text) and we miss out on the duplicates that show up later?

I shudder at the thought that I've been using remove duplicates incorrectly all this while.

Please help. Thanks.

**EDIT To Include the actual file I am working with:**

[Link here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4tcwo2ZvQCRVTlESnVEV1ZORU0/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: @pnuts Thank you!! When the numbers I calculated earlier didn't match up with the ones I calculated yesterday, I spent an hour thinking I was a moron who could not even delete duplicates in excel with some competence. Phew..and yay!! dementia is still at bay!!

Answer (score 1):

seems like you want to ensure is that they're all the same type, no? an easy way to coerce a cell to be text is:

`=A1 & ""`

and a number is:

`=A1 * 1`

Comment: that doesn't actually coerce types though (at least in excel 2010)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to accomplish this by using the Text to Columns option.

1. Select column (B)
2. Select Text to Columns on the Data Tab
3. Select delimited click next
4. Click next as there are no delimiters
5. Under column data format select Text
6. Then remove duplicates

I ran into this issue with VLookup before as well it ensures proper formatting of all data in the column.